# In clause in Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-server-2008-r2

I have simple SQL query as:

```
select * from EH_PP_DmainComps
where domainCode in (1,2)
```

I want to make same query in LINQ.

I made it as:

```
from a in context.EH_PP_DmainComps
                where a.domainCode.ToString().Contains(id)
                select new Entity.correlations(a)
```

Note: id in a.domainCode.ToString().Contains(id) has value (1,2) which is to be used within `In Clause`.

But its not working.

How can i form this simple query in LINQ??

Comment: I guess you wanted to write id.Contains() .

Comment: @RandRandom  id is simple string containing "1,2,3" which i want to check with a.domainCode

Comment: Than it's still id.Contains(), a larger string/array contains a smaller fragment. Contains doesn't say a small fragment is within larger. It's the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you mean:

```
from a in context.EH_PP_DmainComps
where id.Contains(a.domainCode.ToString())
select new Entity.correlations(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should follow the following steps

1- declare your list of id - `var idList = new List<int>(){1,2}`
2- use your linq query like this `from a in context.EH_PP_DmainComps where idList.Contains(a.domainCode) select new correlations(a)`